How to handle routing in a remote app (in React) while using it inside the host app (Angular)
I have an Angular application with title1 and button1, which when clicked, routes to '/hello' (handled by Angular router). I am rendering title2 and button2 which is in React. When I click on button2, it should navigate to '/hi' (handled by react-router-dom). I am using Module Federation to expose the React remote app to my Angular host app. If I remove the routing functionality in my React app, it is being rendered properly but as soon as I add routing, i.e. include any function from react-router-dom, it throws error. All the shared packages have the same versions. Is, what I am trying, achievable?
config-overrides.js (React remote) -
const { override } = require('customize-cra');
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack').container.ModuleFederationPlugin;

module.exports = override(config => {
  config = {
    ...config,
    entry: './src/index',
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
      port: 3000,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
    },
    output: {
      publicPath: 'auto',
    },
  }
  config.plugins.push(
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'reactApp',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './App': './src/App',
      },
      shared: {
        "react": {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: '18.3.1', // Match your React version
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: '18.3.1', // Match your React-DOM version
        },
        "react-router-dom": {
        singleton: true,
        eager: true,
        requiredVersion: '6.26.2',
        },
      },
    })
  );
  return config;
});

webpack.config.js (Angular host) -
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "angularApp",
    publicPath: "http://localhost:4200",
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...mf.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "angularApp",
      remotes: {
        reactApp : "reactApp@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry",
      },
      shared: {
        "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '~13.3.0' },
        "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '~13.3.0' },
        "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '~13.3.0' },
        "rxjs": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '~7.5.0' },
        "react": {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: '18.3.1',
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: '18.3.1',
        },
        "react-router-dom": {
        singleton: true,
        eager: true,
        requiredVersion: '6.26.2',
        },
      }
    }),
  ],
};

App.js (React remote) -
import { Route, Router, RouterProvider, createHashRouter, createRoutesFromElements } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import HomePage from './HomePage';
import HiPage from './HiPage';

const router = createHashRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
      <Route path="/hi" element={<HiPage />} />
    </>
  )
);
function App() {
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
    // <HomePage />
  );
}

export default App;

react-wrapper.component.ts (Angular host) -
import { Component, ElementRef, OnDestroy, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { loadRemoteModule } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-react-wrapper',
  template: '<div #reactContainer></div>',
})
export class ReactWrapperComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('reactContainer', { static: true }) reactContainer!: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.loadComponent();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.reactContainer.nativeElement);
  }

  public loadComponent(): Promise<any> {
    return loadRemoteModule({
        remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js',
        remoteName: 'reactApp',
        exposedModule: './App'
    })
    .then((m) => {
      const Component = m.default;
      ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Component), this.reactContainer.nativeElement);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
    });
  }
}

app-routing.module.ts (Angular host) -
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello/hello.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page/home-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomePageComponent },
  { path: 'hello', component: HelloComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

app.component.ts (Angular host) -
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    // This method is called after component initialization
    console.log('AppComponent initialized');
  }
  navigateToHello(){
    this.router.navigate(['/hello']);
  }
}

home-page.component.ts -
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  template: `
    <h1>Home Page Angular!</h1>
    <button (click)="navigateToHello()">Angular routing to '/hello'</button>
    <app-react-wrapper></app-react-wrapper>
  `,
})
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    // This method is called after component initialization
    console.log('HomePageComponent initialized');
  }
  navigateToHello() {
    this.router.navigate(['/hello']);
  }
}

without routing code, react button doesn't do anything
The above image is when I have commented the routing code in my React App.
with routing code, React stops rendering
The above image is when I am using the routing code in my React App. It stops rendering my React App inside the Angular App.
I tried using different routing instead of the hashed routing in my React App, but still it gave the same result i.e. the React App stopped rendering and only Angular part was rendered. I was expecting the React component to be rendered and the routing to work after I pressed on the react button. Can someone please guide me how I should make it work? I have also tried using bridge-react from module federation but I think it is available only for React and not Angular so Angular won't be able to use the remote React App exposed via bridge-react.
